# Sorting by last name and first name c#

Tags: c#, string, sorting

This is another homework here. I need to sort students by it's last name and first name (firstly last name and secondly first name). The full list of students must be edited alphabetical.

**What works so far:**

If i type in 3 students with same Last name, it sorts correctly.

**Lets say**:

Richardson Mark
Richardson Mike
Richardson Matt

The correct sorting order is:

Richardson Mark
Richardson Matt
Richardson Mike

It also work when last name's start with same letter and are look alike

**Lets say**:

Richardson Mark
Richmond Luke
Rikkard Matt

**Sorts as**:

Richardson Mark
Richmond Luke
Rikkard Matt

**My problem**

The code doesn't sort 3 entirely different last name's (etc, Richardson, Markson, Bekhs)...

Please notice that only basic functions are allowed and must be programmed like bellow!

```
private static void sortAlpphabetical(Student[] studentList)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < studentList.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < studentList.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            string lastName1 = studentList[j].lastName.ToLower() + studentList[j].name.ToLower();
            string lastName2 = studentList[j + 1].lastName.ToLower() + studentList[j + 1].name.ToLower();
            for (int k = 0; k < lastName1.Length; k++)
            {
                if (returnIndex(lastName2[k]) > returnIndex(lastName1[k]))
                {
                    Student currentStudent = studentList[j];
                    studentList[j] = studentList[j + 1];
                    studentList[j + 1] = currentStudent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("List of students:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("//code");
    }
}
```

When i try to sort 3 different last names, it gives me **Index was outside the bounds of the array.** Error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in work.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Which line is giving you that error? A copy of the stack trace from the exception would be handy.

Comment: the **if** line, i copied the error and edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k here makes the assumption that lastName1 is longer than lastName2

```
for (int k = 0; k < lastName1.Length; k++)
{
    if (returnIndex(lastName2[k]) > returnIndex(lastName1[k]))
    {
        Student currentStudent = studentList[j];
        studentList[j] = studentList[j + 1];
        studentList[j + 1] = currentStudent;
    }
}
```

This should prevent that by preventing the loop checking beyond the length of which ever is shorter

```
int shortestNameLength = Math.Min(lastName1.Length, lastName2.Length);
for (int k = 0; k < shortestNameLength ; k++)
```

After some testing your algorithm has another problem. It will continue comparing to the last character in the name. It needs to stop once it has determined the order

Compare a character

- If the same, check next character
- If greater, swap, were done here.
- If less, do nothing, were done here.

To summarise, replace

```
for (int k = 0; k < lastName1.Length; k++)
{
    if (returnIndex(lastName2[k]) > returnIndex(lastName1[k]))
    {
        Student currentStudent = studentList[j];
        studentList[j] = studentList[j + 1];
        studentList[j + 1] = currentStudent;
    }
}
```

with

```
int shortestNameLength = Math.Min(lastName1.Length, lastName2.Length);
for (int k = 0; k < shortestNameLength ; k++)
{
    int c1 = returnIndex(lastName1[k]);
    int c2 = returnIndex(lastName2[k]);
    if (c1 == c2)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (c1 > c2)
    {
        Student currentStudent = studentList[j];
        studentList[j] = studentList[j + 1];
        studentList[j + 1] = currentStudent;
    }
    break;
}
```

The complete method now looks something like this...

```
    private static void sortAlpphabetical(Student[] studentList)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < studentList.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < studentList.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                string lastName1 = studentList[j].lastName.ToLower() + studentList[j].name.ToLower();
                string lastName2 = studentList[j + 1].lastName.ToLower() + studentList[j + 1].name.ToLower();
                int shortestNameLength = Math.Min(lastName1.Length, lastName2.Length);
                for (int k = 0; k < shortestNameLength; k++)
                {
                    int c1 = returnIndex(lastName1[k]);
                    int c2 = returnIndex(lastName2[k]);
                    if (c1 == c2)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (c1 > c2)
                    {
                        Student currentStudent = studentList[j];
                        studentList[j] = studentList[j + 1];
                        studentList[j + 1] = currentStudent;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("List of students:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < studentList.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", studentList[i].name, studentList[i].lastName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: where i am suppose to add this. before or after the **if**?

Comment: @fkr Instead of, it replaces the if

Comment: you also need the change to the for loop, I'll edit my answer to be clearer

Comment: ok it works now, BUT it sorts in opposite alphabetical way (etc....Smoke, Poke, Hoke, instead of ...Hoke, Poke, Smoke

Comment: @fkr Either change > to < or swap c1 and c2

Comment: i did try that before i replied here and nothing has changed. blows my mind. Either > or < ,sorts the same. Yeah it does blow my mind

Comment: @fkr Sorry can't help you there, I've run the algorithm on my machine and it works as expected. There must be another mistake in your code.

Comment: Well thank you for your time and everything..ill try to figure sth out. Ill mark your answer is the right one:)

Comment: one more question...if you look at my original post...must there something be changed with **for** at the bottom, after the console.writeline?

Comment: @fkr I've added the complete method I used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length of the arrays you're accessing.  If `lastName1` doesn't have a character at offset `k` (i.e. `lastName1.length == k`), we know `lastName2` is greater than `lastName1`.  If `lastName2` does not have a character at offset `k` (i.e. `lastName2.length <= k`), it can't be greater than `lastName1`.

Change

```
if (returnIndex(lastName2[k]) > returnIndex(lastName1[k]))
```

to

```
if( lastName1.length == k ||
    ( lastName2.length > k &&
      returnIndex(lastName2[k]) > returnIndex(lastName1[k]) ) )
```

Comment: it doesn't sort it in the right way. It's sorts it in the exact same order i typed it in

Comment: it actually sorts it different every time i try

Comment: @fkr see my answer for why

Comment: your sorting algorithm may be wrong; i simply corrected its index out of bounds issue.

Comment: until it threw index out of range exceptions, you mean

Comment: @Moho well it sorts out the one with same lastname, but not with different

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

Student[] sorted = studentList.OrderBy(x=>x.lastName).ThenBy(x=>x.name).ToArray();
```

Comment: i can't use OrderBy. It must be ordered as above.

Comment: Second one should be ThenBy.

Comment: I can't use any "complex" functions. Must be done like mine above

Answer (score 0):

Just scratched this up in LinqPad, which should give you the desired output, unless you are supposed to use for-loops and classic arrays.

```
void Main()
{
    var students = new List<student>() 
    {
      new student("Alphonso", "Zander"),
      new student("Berta", "Zander"),
      new student("Giacomo", "Zander"),
      new student("Marc", "Lastly"),
      new student("God", "Allmighty")
    };

    var sortedStudents = students.OrderBy(s => s.lastName).ThenBy(s => s.firstName).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class student
{
    public student(string fname, string lname)
    {
     this.firstName = fname; this.lastName = lname;
    }
  public string firstName { get; set; }
  public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
firstName lastName 
God       Allmighty 
Marc      Lastly 
Alphonso  Zander 
Berta     Zander 
Giacomo   Zander
```

Comment: i cannot use OrderBy. It's forbidden

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to specify the order of your objects.

This is the code I scrapped in LinqPad (using the names provided by **@Serv** - yeah I am *that* lazy...)

```
void Main()
{
    var students = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student("Alphonso", "Zander"),
        new Student("Berta", "Zander"),
        new Student("Giacomo", "Zander"),
        new Student("Marc", "Lastly"),
        new Student("God", "Allmighty")
    };
    students.Sort(new StudentComparer());
    students.Dump();
}

class Student
{
    public Student(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}

class StudentComparer:IComparer<Student>
{
    public int Compare(Student a, Student b)
    {
        var lastName = a.LastName.CompareTo(b.LastName);
        if(lastName == 0)
            return a.FirstName.CompareTo(b.FirstName);
        return lastName;
    }   
}
```

Unless you want to rewrite the sorting algorithm used by `Sort` method the code above should suffice for you.

And here are the results:

[image: Results.]

Comment: thank you very much but this is supposed to be not a complex program, which means i cannot use either Icomparer or CompareTo. Subject rules, not mine =\